# MenuCollection Binding twice MVVM + Databinding Child menu items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, menuitem

As you can see in the image below, you can see 2 hover states.  Here is the XAML

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Data.MenuCollection}">
    <Menu.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate DataType="MenuItem">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}" Command="{Binding Command}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemTemplate>
</Menu>
```

The Collection of data works on the header. However I can't get the Children nodes to appear.

```
public void CreateTempMenuList()
{
    MenuCollection = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>()
    {
        new MenuItem()
        {
            Header = "File",
            Children = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>()
            {
                new MenuItem()
                {
                    Header = "Exit"
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The `MenuItem` class is something I created. Each property has a setter that called the `OnPropertiesChanged` Function. I can add the class if needed, but I am pretty sure thats not the problem.

So my question is. How do i get rid of the `'double' hover`. In the image you can see 2 `borders`. An `outer border` which i hover over. the hover stays until focused on something else.

My second question is how can i get the child items to work?  The `itemssource` on the `menuitem` tag could be wrong but its all i could think of.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an `HierarchicalDataTemplate`:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Data.MenuCollection}">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <Menu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemTemplate>
</Menu>
```

A `System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem` container is implicitly created for each item so you shouldn't add another `MenuItem` element in the template.

Also make sure that you don't bind to an `ObservableCollection<System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem>` because the `ItemTemplate` won't be applied to built-in `MenuItem` elements.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. And yes I am not binding to the system MenuItem Class, I have built my own class for that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To make your current code work, right click your `Menu control > Edit Additional Template > Edit ItemContainerStyle > Edit Copy`.

And in the generated Style,

Search for this piece of code :

```
           <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
            </Trigger>
```

And change `Padding` to `0` instead of `7,2,8,3` .

Comment: This imo seems 'hacky'. I apprecaite the answer.

Comment: @A.Mills You should also know whats happening behind the scene.